# How to get sensor data from HAF Honeywell Zephyr flow sensor (AXT series) on raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, i2c, honeywell

I have setup a honeywell flow sensor (AXT) , however I am struggling to interpret data coming from the sensor. I have the following code :

```
import smbus
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x49
bear1=bus.read_byte_data(address,0x01)
print(bear1)
```

Returns me output : `204`
As can be seen from the datasheet, 0x01 is supposed to give me the serial number, which is 20L4 in a small label attached to the back of the sensor. For some reason the output misses the character L.

Another snippet for printing response from first 7 addresses:

```
import sys
import board
import busio
i2c=busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
print('i2c devices',[hex(i) for i in i2c.scan()])
devices=i2c.scan()
device=devices[0]
registers=(0,6)
register_size=2
result=bytearray(register_size)
for register in range(*registers):
  try:
    i2c.writeto(device,bytes([register]))
    i2c.readfrom_into(device,result)
  except OSError:
    continue
  print('Address {0} contains value : {1}'.format(register,' '.join([hex(x) for x in result])))
```

Output :

```
i2c devices ['0x49']
Address 0 contains value : 0x6 0x69
Address 1 contains value : 0x4e 0x17
Address 2 contains value : 0x4e 0x17
Address 3 contains value : 0x4e 0x17
Address 4 contains value : 0x4e 0x17
Address 5 contains value : 0xcc 0x99
```

How do I interpret data from sensor? I have uploaded the datasheet [HERE](https://easyupload.io/s555l7)[image: snapshot]

Comment: Can you share the interface control document (ICD) or datasheet of the sensor? Its very difficult to comment by just looking at your code.

Comment: @DarkSorrow, datasheet uploaded now https://easyupload.io/s555l7

Comment: Try using `read_block_data(int addr,char cmd)` to read serial number.