# How to interpret HAF sensor data?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors, i2c

My sensor i2c - (flow sensor) on raspberry pi gives a reading `b'\x06g'`. How can |I possibly interpret this?
Code snippet used (this code is based on - https://github.com/stripemsu/HoneywellFlow)

```
import io, fcntl

I2C_SLAVE=0x0703
I2C_BUS=1
HAFAddr=0x49
maxflow=100 #100 sccm
toHex = lambda x: ''.join([hex(ord(c))[2:].zfill(2) for c in x])
i2c_r=io.open("/dev/i2c-"+str(I2C_BUS),"rb",buffering=0)
i2c_w=io.open("/dev/i2c-"+str(I2C_BUS),"wb",buffering=0)
fcntl.ioctl(i2c_r, I2C_SLAVE,HAFAddr)
print(i2c_r.read(2))
i2c_r.close()
```

I have uploaded the datasheet of the sensor [HERE](https://easyupload.io/s555l7) [image: snapshot]

Comment: You didn't say which device you are using or provide a link to its description/specifications. Are you sure you want to open the same device twice - normally you can just open for write access and that allows read and write.

Comment: The value `b'\x06g` is a two-byte sequence where the first byte is a `6` and the second byte is `103`. We can't tell you how to interpret those numbers -- only your sensor's data sheet could answer that question. Maybe MSB  and LSB for a reading? Maybe a single byte status code and a single byte reading? The answers will be in the data sheet.

Comment: Hello @MarkSetchell, the device is Honeywell Zephyr HAF (AXT) series flow sensor , coupled with a raspberrypi board

Comment: @mrin9san Can you share the interface control document (ICD) or datasheet of the sensor? Its very difficult to comment by just looking at your code.

Comment: @DarkSorrow, I have uploaded the datasheet now - https://easyupload.io/s555l7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `b'\x06g'.hex()` gives `0x0667` (converts bytes codes to hex representation).

Seems like the data you are getting is `0x0667`, or `0b0000 0110 0110 0111`. The page 6 of the datasheet gives the digital output vs flow scale. 0x0667 is roughly 10% of the maximum. (in decimal, it can be interpreted as a value of 1639 over the maximum possible value of 16384 (2^14)).

So, the simplest interpretation you could do is to calculate the ratio of the obtained value over the maximum output value (2^14, or 16384). This will probably not give optimal results though, I'm sure some sort of calibration is needed and is surely described in details in the datasheet.

Comment: The code seems right , ain't it? I feel you made a very valid observation.

Comment: At a quick glance, I can't see anything wrong with the I2C part of the code. Is there a way for you to play with the sensor and make the digital output vary? That could help confirm that the behavior is as intended. Another thing you could do is ask for the sensor's serial number (if you have the actual number written somewhere to counter verify it).

Comment: yes i have a small snippet written for serial number as well. In follwoing post I obtain a output 204 whereas actual device serial number is 20L4, I dont know why L didnt show up ..but i guess its not coinincidence. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75145892/how-to-get-sensor-data-from-haf-honeywell-zephyr-flow-sensor-axt-series-on-ras?noredirect=1#comment132623191_75145892